# How to set the Property: hbm2dll.auto?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I would like to set the following property:

Property: hbm2dll.auto

- validate = validates the whole database schema
- create = creates the whole database schema

How I can do this with Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: I generally control this behavior myself in a method called UpdateSchema() where I just call the SchemaUpdate() method in NHibernate like so: new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate( config ).Execute( false, true );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported directly through the Fluent NHibernate API. However, you could just add it to the created configuration:

```
Configuration config = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(...)
    .Mappings(m =>
        {
            ...
        })
    .BuildConfiguration();

config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Hbm2ddlAuto, "validate");
```